# In Django : How can I multiply two columns and save to another column in update query?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

```
class A(models.Model):
    revenue = models.FloatField()
    list_price = models.FloatField()
    unit_sold = models.FloatField()
```

I have this model which has 1M records in list_price and unit_sold
I want to fill revenue column using list_price * unit_sold

Answer (score 1):

In overwrite your `save` function in the form, add `result = list_price * unit_sold` before save.

```py
    def save(self, commit=True):
        A = super(AForm, self).save(commit=False)
        revenue = list_price * unit_sold

        if commit:
            A.save()
        return A
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need query which will update revenue column:
that will be more helpful